# Dimension of $Image(T)$ and $Image(T^2)$

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

> Given a $4\times4$ real matrix $A$, let $T:\mathbb R^4\to \mathbb R^4$ be the linear transformation defined by $Tv=Av$, where we think of $\mathbb R^4$ as the set of real $4\times1$ matrices. For which choices of $A$ given below, do the $Image(T)$ and $Image(T^2)$ have respective dimension 2 and 1?
>
> * denotes a non zero entry
>
> $1.A=\left[\begin{matrix}0&&0&&*&&*\\
> 0&&0&&*&&*\\
> 0&&0&&0&&*\\
> 0&&0&&0&&0\end{matrix}\right]$
>
> $2.A=\left[\begin{matrix}0&&0&&*&&0\\
> 0&&0&&*&&0\\
> 0&&0&&0&&*\\
> 0&&0&&0&&*\end{matrix}\right]$
>
> $3.A=\left[\begin{matrix}0&&0&&0&&0\\
> 0&&0&&0&&0\\
> 0&&0&&0&&*\\
> 0&&0&&*&&0\end{matrix}\right]$
>
> $4.A=\left[\begin{matrix}0&&0&&0&&0\\
> 0&&0&&0&&0\\
> 0&&0&&*&&*\\
> 0&&0&&*&&*\end{matrix}\right]$

1. [is right here](/questions/1337305/dimension-of-the-image-of-a-linear-transformation): $\dim A=2$,$A^2=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & * \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & * \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$,$\dim A^2=1$
2. $A$ is of rank 2 and of $A^2=\left[\begin{matrix}0&&0&&0&&*\\
   0&&0&&0&&*\\
   0&&0&&0&&*\\
   0&&0&&0&&*\end{matrix}\right]$ is 1.
3. $\text{rank A=rank }A^2=2$
4. $\text{rank A}$,$\text{rank }A^2$ may even be 1 itself or bot can be two, depending on non zero elements.

What confuses me is 1 and 2 satisfies the required conditions, and among these, only one is supposed to be the right choice. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: $\dim A$ is bad notation, matrices do not have dimensions, spaces have, replace $\dim A$ by $\def\r{\mathop{\rm rank}}\r A$ or $\dim \def\i{\mathop{\rm image}}\i T$.

Now: You are right, (1) and (2) are both possible answers. But why is only one supposed to be a right choice? I do not think that this is implied by the wording of the exercise.

Comment: Corrected as you pointed out! And this is a question from section of a competitive exam question paper where only one is supposed to be correct answer! Thank you! :)

Comment: They acknowledged that its a mistake! :-)